# Operate on varying sized sequential array slices

Tags: python, numpy, time-series

Lets say I have the following `signal` array, where each value corresponds to a time in the `time` array:

```
np.random.seed(123)
time = np.array([0,2,4,7,10,11,12,17,21,25,29,30,31,40])  # in seconds
signal = np.random.randint(1,5,len(time))
```

What I want to do is slice the `signal` array into smaller arrays, such that the time span of each slice is *at least* 10 seconds long. Then sum `signal` for each slice. Visually:

```
         |-----sum------||-----sum------||---sum----||--X--
time   = 0,  2,  4,  7, 10, 11, 12, 17, 21, 25, 29, 31, 40
signal = 3,  2,  3,  3,  1,  3,  3,  2,  4,  3,  4,  3,  2
```

My desired output is a list containing the sum of `signal` for each 10 second slice:

```
[12,  # 3+2+3+3+1
 13,  # 1+3+3+2+4
 14]  # 4+3+4+3
```

Note that the final 2 `signal` elements don't get summed because the time difference there is less than 10 seconds

I wrote the following function:

```
def count(x, time, epoch=60):
    # calculate time diff
    time = time - time[0]

    # get indices at time boundaries
    num_bins = int(max(time) / epoch)
    inds = [0]

    for i in range(num_bins):
        upper_ind = np.argmax(time >= time[inds[-1]] + epoch)

        if time[upper_ind] - time[inds[-1]] >= epoch:
            inds.append(upper_ind)

    # calculate sums between each boundary
    counts = []
    for i in range(len(inds) - 1):
        lower = inds[i]
        upper = inds[i+1] + 1

        cur_signal = x[lower:upper]

        counts.append(sum(cur_signal))

    return counts
```

Which is called by:

```
counts = count(signal, time, epoch=10)
```

It works, but its slow for large arrays and quite hacky. Is there a more efficient way to do this, maybe with some numpy magic, where I don't have to go through to determine the boundaries, and then go through again to get the sum?

Bonus points if theres a way to linearly interpolate between 2 time points (i.e. if the one prior is slightly short of 10s, and the next time is slightly more than 10s) by estimating the value of `signal` at exact 10 second intervals

EDIT:

Just to roll in some additional info from the comments...

at least 10 seconds long means the slices cannot be shorter than 10s, but can be longer. I'll take the first time point that is greater than 10s. See the second slice in my example above

signal values at the boundaries are to be counted twice. In other words, the end value of one slice is the starting value of the next

Comment: "*at least 10 seconds long*" means that you can select longer spans?!

Comment: yes. but nothing shorter. I want the first time that is at least 10 seconds. the second slice in my example is an example of this

Comment: Some elements in your `signal` are counted twice (like the 5th value, `1`). Just to clarify, last element of one slice is also the 1st element of the next slice?

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: What if the second last element in time is not there and correspondingly second last element in signal is removed. i.e. time is - `[ 0,  2,  4,  7, 10, 11, 12, 17, 21, 25, 29, 30, 40]` and signal - `[ 3,  2,  3,  3,  1,  3,  3,  2,  4,  3,  4,  2,  2]`. What must be the output then? The loopy code doesn't seem to work in that case, hence this query.

Comment: Just double checked and I think the code is correct. Those inputs should give `[12, 13, 15]`. The final slice in that case will be `4+3+4+2+2` and will cover quite a large time span (21 to 40 seconds) - its over 10, buts its the first available so its OK

Comment: you define time `...,29,30,31...` but in your visual example you skip the 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit

After thinking about this for a bit, I realize that your best bet is probably not elegant numpy code, especially if you're concerned about performance. Even @PaulPanzer's code, beautiful as it is, relies on calling `searchsorted` (which is based on a relatively expensive binary search) in a loop.

Instead, you can just do your whole algorithm in a one-pass loop with no search:

```
signal = np.array([3,  2,  3,  3,  1,  3,  3,  2,  4,  3,  4,  3,  2])
time = np.array([0,  2,  4,  7, 10, 11, 12, 17, 21, 25, 29, 31, 40])

def count(signal, time, epoch=10):
    counts = []
    total = 0
    timestart = times[0]

    for x,t in zip(signal, time):
        total += x

        if t - timestart >= epoch:
            counts.append(total)
            total = x
            timestart = t

    return counts

count(signal, time)
```

Output:

```
[12, 13, 14]
```

## Timings

It does appear that the simple loop is indeed a good bit faster than the numpy/`searchsorted`/`where` approaches.

My code:

```
%%timeit        
count(signal, time)

5.88 µs ± 165 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

@PaulPanzer's code:

```
%%timeit
idx = np.fromiter(iter(accumulate(chain((0,), repeat(10)), lambda now, delta: time.searchsorted(time[now] + delta)).__next__, len(time)), int)
np.add.reduceat(signal[:idx[-1]], idx[:-1]) + signal[idx[1:]]

9.63 µs ± 182 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

@Brenlla's code:

```
%%timeit
out=[]
prev=0
# need to reinitialize the time array since the loop eats it
time = np.array([0,  2,  4,  7, 10, 11, 12, 17, 21, 25, 29, 31, 40])
while True:
    try:
        idx10 = np.where(time >=10)[0][0]
        time-=time[idx10]
        out.append(np.sum(signal[prev:idx10+1]))
        prev=idx10
    except:
        break

30.1 µs ± 502 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using a combination of `itertools` and `numpy`:

```
>>> time   = 0,  2,  4,  7, 10, 11, 12, 17, 21, 25, 29, 31, 40
>>> signal = 3,  2,  3,  3,  1,  3,  3,  2,  4,  3,  4,  3,  2
>>> time, signal = map(np.array, (time, signal))
>>> 
>>> idx = np.fromiter(iter(accumulate(chain((0,), repeat(10)), lambda now, delta: time.searchsorted(time[now] + delta)).__next__, len(time)), int)
>>> np.add.reduceat(signal[:idx[-1]], idx[:-1]) + signal[idx[1:]]
array([12, 13, 14])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vectorized and Numpythonic approach:

```
# time is array([ 2,  2,  4,  7, 10, 11, 12, 17, 21, 25, 29, 30, 31, 40])

# Using broadcasting you can get a 2d array of the difference of all items
# from other items within your array
In [115]: arr = time[:, None] - time
# Then find indices where the difference is less and equal to -10
In [116]: x, y = np.where(arr <= -10)
# find the first occurrences of where for each item the difference is less and equal to -10 
In [117]: first_acc = np.concatenate(([0], np.where(np.diff(x) != 0)[0]  + 1, [x.size]))

# use a recursive generator function to retrieve all the expected indices.
In [118]: def get_ind_rec(ind=0):
     ...:     try:
     ...:         ind = y[first_acc[ind]]
     ...:         yield ind
     ...:         yield from get_ind_rec(ind)
     ...:     except: # IndexError
     ...:         pass
     ...:     
     ...:     

In [119]: list(get_ind_rec())
Out[119]: [6, 9, 13]
```

Now you can simply use `np.split()` to split the `signal` based on these indices and use `map` to apply the `sum` on all slices.

Answer (score 1):

Also a bit hacky, but I find it easy to understand. Probably need to replace `try ... except` with something more robust/elegant

```
time   = 0,  2,  4,  7, 10, 11, 12, 17, 21, 25, 29, 31, 40
signal = 3,  2,  3,  3,  1,  3,  3,  2,  4,  3,  4,  3,  2
time, signal = map(np.array, (time, signal))

out=[]
prev=0
while True:
    try:
        idx10 = np.where(time >=10)[0][0]
        time-=time[idx10]
        out.append(sum(signal[prev:idx10+1]))
        prev=idx10
    except:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

### If a compiler is an option

If a problem isn't trivial to solve using numpy and broadcasting this should be always a alternative. Even if vectorizing is simple to do on a problem you can often gain significant speedups.

**Loop as much as you want**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def count(x, time, epoch=10):
  max_bins=int((time[-1]-time[0]))//epoch
  sum_arr=np.zeros((max_bins),dtype=x.dtype)

  start_time=time[0]
  ii=0
  for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    if (time[i]-start_time) < epoch:
      sum_arr[ii]+=x[i]
    else:
      sum_arr[ii]+=x[i]
      ii+=1
      sum_arr[ii]+=x[i]
      start_time=time[i]

  return sum_arr[0:ii]
```

**Compile it**

In this example I use numba, because of its simplicity. The import and the function decorator is all you need to gain some orders of magnitude speedup.

**Measuring performance**

```
#create some data
t=np.arange(0,1e6,2)
signal = np.random.randint(1,5,len(t))
sum_arr=count(signal, t, epoch=10)

t1=time.time()
sum_arr_1=your_count(signal, t, epoch=10)
print(time.time()-t1)

#The first call gets about 0.2s compilation overhead
sum_arr_2=count(signal, t, epoch=10)

t1=time.time()
for i in range(1000):
  sum_arr_2=count(signal, t, epoch=10)

print((time.time()-t1)/1000)
np.allclose(sum_arr_1,sum_arr_2)
```

**Results**

```
your_version:13.6s
compiled_version: 0.6ms
np.allclose: True
```

So all in all a speedup of **20200x**.